# Consume POST data on react

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, form-data

We are calling a payment gateway api and that vendor is sending response with some POST method. Our UI is build in react which is not able to consume that data. How can I do that?

Comment: if vendor is sending `POST` request, there must be a server to receive that request... from that server send a response to your react app

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, here it's better if they send it using `GET`. If you want to consume the data then this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is CCAvenue, you will need a server to take that response and redirect you back to React with the necessary details.

Comment: Not CCAvenue its FirstData... Now I have made a POST method which they can call. They are sending data in FORMData. How could I consume FORM Data on my Java api endpoint